# In a popup, change text in a span

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onchange

I was trying to add an external JavaScript file to my HTML for a practice Chrome extension. It has a slider whose value needs to be taken and sent back to a span tag on the *popup.html*,
As I looked up I need to have a separate JavaScript file and create an `onchange` event listener to take the element and pass its value. But I cannot get the value to show on span tag. Please guide on what I am doing wrong.

This is the HTML (popup.html)

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
   <title>Slide</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" id="slider" />
     <span id="range">0</span>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And This is the JavaScript file (popup.js)

```
 document.getElementById("slider").onchange = function() {showValue()};


 function showValue()
 { 
    var newValue = document.getElementById("slider");
    var rng = document.getElementById("range");
    rng.value = newValue.value;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct except one line in your `popup.js` file

Change

`rng.value = newValue.value;`

To

`rng.textContent = newValue.value;`

because you want change the text inside the tag.

```js
document.getElementById("slider").onchange = function() {showValue()};

function showValue()
{
  var newValue = document.getElementById("slider");
  var rng = document.getElementById("range");
  rng.textContent = newValue.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" id="slider" />
<span id="range">0</span>
```

Comment: To change a text value, [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is a better choice than `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Yes `textContent` has better performance than `innerHTML`. Changed it in the answer.